# laravel sync can't save data

Tags: php, laravel, synchronization

I am trying to use sync method in pivot relationship but it does not save data correctly.

## Logic

1. Organization can have many admins
2. user can be admin of 1 organization only

#### Tables

1. users
2. organizations
3. organization_admins  // saves `organization_id` and `user_id`

## Models

**User**

```
public function organization()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Organization::class, 'superAdmin_id', 'id');
}

public function organizationAdmins()
{
    return $this->hasOne(OrganizationAdmin::class, 'organization_admins', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

**Organization**

```
public function superAdmin()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'superAdmin_id', 'id');
}
public function admins()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(OrganizationAdmin::class, 'organization_admins', 'organization_id', 'id');
}
```

**OrganizationAdmin**

```
public function organization()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Organization::class, 'organization_admins', 'id', 'organization_id');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //...
    $organization->save();
    $admins = $request->input('user_id');
    $organization->admins()->sync($admins); //saving admins in pivot table
}
```

**Result**

This is what saves in database **info of user wont save**

[image: one]

**Any idea?**

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane it's array like `["1" , "3"]` that's why i 've got 2 rows in my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix this

**Organization**

```
public function admins()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(OrganizationAdmin::class, 'organization_admins', 'organization_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: wow! it works :) but how do i force it to save timestamp as well?

Comment: fixed :) need to use `->withTimestamps()`

Comment: Yes need use `->withTimestamps();`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
public function admins()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(OrganizationAdmin::class, 'organization_admins', 'organization_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

For more information read [Many to many eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)